# How to rearrange output for shell script

Tags: bash

Given the following shell script,how do I rearrange the output in order to insert a new line?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e $1 ` date `
```

I tried the -e switch but to no avail.

I mean if I type: `./script.sh "`ls -la`"` I get the following output:

```
total 4732 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2013-01-09 15:32 . drwx------ 28 root root 4096 2013-01-09 15:32 .. -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 484063 2013-01-06 05:22 Blackhat-europe-09-Damele-SQLInjection-whitepaper.pdf -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3787587 2013-01-06 05:10 FoxitReader-1.1.0.tar.bz2 -r-------- 1 root root 127693 2013-01-03 22:55 HackYeah-SQL-Injection.pdf drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2013-01-05 21:47 Inst_DVWA -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3223 2012-12-22 00:47 nmap-O -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 284 2013-01-06 07:31 payload_dvwa.txt -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 2013-01-09 11:18 script (copy).sh -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 2013-01-09 15:32 script.sh -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 395493 2013-01-06 05:03 SQLmap_README.pdf -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 705 2013-01-07 15:22 start_dvwa.sh -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 834 2013-01-06 07:31 Unsaved Document 1.txt drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-12-19 18:47 ZAP_certificate Wed Jan 9 15:32:55 CET 2013
```

I'd like to get an output similar to this:

```
total 4732
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4096 2013-01-09 15:32 .
drwx------ 28 root root    4096 2013-01-09 15:32 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  484063 2013-01-06 05:22 Blackhat-europe-09-Damele-SQLInjection-whitepaper.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 3787587 2013-01-06 05:10 FoxitReader-1.1.0.tar.bz2
-r--------  1 root root  127693 2013-01-03 22:55 HackYeah-SQL-Injection.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 2013-01-05 21:47 Inst_DVWA
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    3223 2012-12-22 00:47 nmap-O 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     284 2013-01-06 07:31 payload_dvwa.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      30 2013-01-09 11:18 script (copy).sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      33 2013-01-09 15:32 script.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  395493 2013-01-06 05:03 SQLmap_README.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root     705 2013-01-07 15:22 start_dvwa.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     834 2013-01-06 07:31 Unsaved Document 1.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 2012-12-19 18:47 ZAP_certificate
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: where is the output from `\`date\`` in your sample output? What processing is your `bash` script meant to perform on the `ls -la` that is your argument? Good luck.

Comment: If your script actually looks like that, the output of `./script.sh "ls -la"` will be `ls -la Wed Jan 9 09:52:22 EST 2013`.  I don't think that's what you want but it's hard to be sure from your question.  Show us (a) your actual script, (b) the output that it produces right now, and (c) the output you would like it to produce.  And trim the number of lines in the output; you don't need so many.

Comment: Your attempt repeats a common newbie antipattern: Useless Use of Backticks. See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo -e "`$1`\n`date`"
```

The quotes should preserve the newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#!/bin/bash
$*
date
```

I'm not sure how `./script "ls -la"` is an improvement over `ls -la; date` but I suppose you have your reasons.

As a crucial usability improvement, I would prefer `./script ls -la` without the quotes, though; just switch `"$@"` for `$*`. Then, among other things, passing in quoted strings as arguments will also work. For example, `./script perl -le 'print 0x12, "foo"'`